# How to solve this Flutter inlt Hms error?

Tags: flutter, time, intl

```
reminingTimeDiff() async {

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
var now2 = DateFormat.Hms().format(now);
var time = await DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("${widget.cPrayerTime}");
var time2 = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("$now2");
var diff = time.difference(time2);

// If difference is negative, add 24 hours
if (diff.inSeconds < 0) {
  diff = diff + Duration(hours: 24);
}

setState(() {
  reminingTime = diff;
});
```

} it gives me a error I use inlt package for format and set to remingTime

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read HH from  at 0
```

Comment: hey, please tell me what is widget.cPrayerTimen exact data, i think it's because of wrong data in widget.cPrayerTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly have mistake or wrong data in `widget.cPrayerTime`.

see what's happening in my code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Duration reminingTime = Duration();
  String cPrayerTime = "HH";

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('cPrayerTime: $cPrayerTime \n'),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => reminingTimeDiff(),
                  child: Text('$reminingTime'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  reminingTimeDiff() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var now2 = DateFormat.Hms().format(now);
    var time = await DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("${cPrayerTime}");
    var time2 = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("$now2");
    var diff = time.difference(time2);

    print('diff: $diff');
// If difference is negative, add 24 hours
    if (diff.inSeconds < 0) {
      diff = diff + Duration(hours: 24);
    }

    setState(() {
      reminingTime = diff;
    });
  }
}
```

here is screenshot:

[image]

and if you click on  `Text('$reminingTime')` you will see that we have exception

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read HH from HH at
> position 0

because you have wrong data in `cPrayerTime`.

and now see:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Duration reminingTime = Duration();
  String cPrayerTime = "22:11:33"; // this line changed

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('cPrayerTime: $cPrayerTime \n'),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => reminingTimeDiff(),
                  child: Text('$reminingTime'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  reminingTimeDiff() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var now2 = DateFormat.Hms().format(now);
    var time = await DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("${cPrayerTime}");
    var time2 = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("$now2");
    var diff = time.difference(time2);

    print('diff: $diff');
// If difference is negative, add 24 hours
    if (diff.inSeconds < 0) {
      diff = diff + Duration(hours: 24);
    }

    setState(() {
      reminingTime = diff;
    });
  }
}
```

and now we don't have any exception if you click on  `Text('$reminingTime')`:

[image]

happy coding...